# lines disappear in the history of bash : is this a bug or a feature?

Tags: bash

When I enter a command line starting with a space, the line does not appear in the history of bash (using the up arrow).

Is this a bug or a feature of bash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature.

From the manual page:

```
       HISTCONTROL
              A colon-separated list of values controlling  how  commands  are
              saved  on  the  history  list.   If  the list of values includes
              ignorespace, lines which begin with a space  character  are  not
              saved  in  the history list.  A value of ignoredups causes lines
              matching the previous history entry to not be saved.  A value of
              ignoreboth is shorthand for ignorespace and ignoredups.  A value
```

Comment: On redhat, I have HISTCONTROL=ignoredup. On debian, I have HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth. Now I understand what was happening. Thank you !